# how can i restrict my moving image moving out of the canvas in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

i have tried stopping the moving image by using constrain() function but i am unable to perform it .i want to know how could i stop my moving image from moving out of the canvas or at desired location. here is the code

```
var pic1
var pic2
var pic3

let posX=0
let posY=0

function preload(){
  pic1=loadImage("5.png")
  pic2=loadImage("iron.jpg")
  pic3=loadImage("slagmetal.jpg")
  
}
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  text(mouseX + "," + mouseY, 20, 20);
  let rightwall=200
 
  img1=image(pic1,300,0,150,200)
  img2=image(pic2,posX,50,100,100)
  var myDiv=createDiv(pic1);
  myDiv.position(170,30);
  myDiv.size(200,200);
  myDiv.show();
  img3=image(pic3,0,400,200,150)
let
  

  posX+=1
  posY+=1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some general advice:

1. Do not create HTML elements (i.e. calling `createDiv()`) inside of the `draw()` function. The `draw()` function is called many times per second and these divs are persistent, so this would create huge numbers of divs.
2. The `image()` function does not return a value, so assigning it to a local variable doesn't do anything.

Here is a basic example of using `constrain()` to limit the horizontal position of your image:

```js
let pic1;
let pic2;
let pic3;

let posX = 0;
let posY = 0;

const rightwall = 200;

function preload() {
  pic1 = loadImage(pic1DataUrl);
  pic2 = loadImage(pic2DataUrl);
  pic3 = loadImage(pic3DataUrl);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  text(mouseX + "," + mouseY, 20, 20);

  image(pic1, 300, 0, 150, 200)
  image(pic2, posX, 50, 100, 100)
  image(pic3, 0, 400, 200, 150)

  posX = constrain(posX + 1, 0, rightwall - 100);
  posY += 1;
}

const pic1DataUrl = "data:image/png;base64,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";
const pic2DataUrl = "data:image/png;base64,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";
const pic3DataUrl = "data:image/png;base64,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";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Here's an example with additional animations using a construct for updating positions based on starting positions, ending positions, and durations:

```js
let pic1;
let pic2;
let pic3;

const pic1Animation = {
  start: {
    x: 300,
    y: 0
  },
  end: {
    x: 300,
    y: 0
  },
  duration: 0
};
const pic2Animation = {
  start: {
    x: 0,
    y: 50
  },
  end: {
    x: 200,
    y: 50
  },
  duration: 3
};
const pic3Animation = {
  start: {
    x: 0,
    y: 400
  },
  end: {
    x: 100,
    y: 150
  },
  duration: 3
};

function preload() {
  pic1 = loadImage(pic1DataUrl);
  pic2 = loadImage(pic2DataUrl);
  pic3 = loadImage(pic3DataUrl);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  text(mouseX + "," + mouseY, 20, 20);

  drawAnimated(pic1, pic1Animation, 150, 200)
  drawAnimated(pic2, pic2Animation, 100, 100)
  drawAnimated(pic3, pic3Animation, 200, 150)
}

function drawAnimated(pic, animation, w, h) {
  if (animation.duration > millis() / 1000) {
    image(
      pic,
      lerp(animation.start.x, animation.end.x, millis() / 1000 / animation.duration),
      lerp(animation.start.y, animation.end.y, millis() / 1000 / animation.duration),
      w,
      h
    );
  } else {
    image(pic, animation.end.x, animation.end.y, w, h);
  }
}

const pic1DataUrl = "data:image/png;base64,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";
const pic2DataUrl = "data:image/png;base64,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";
const pic3DataUrl = "data:image/png;base64,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";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: after that how could i move the third image towards the location where the other two images meet. in simple way how to move the blue rectangle towards the intersection point of red and green

Comment: You've already demonstrated the concept: don't hard code positions for the images you want to move, use variables like `posX`. If you know where the collision will occur you simply need to determine how much to update the X and Y coordinates by each frame (to be more robust you might want to determine the amount of movement based on time delta rather than incrementing by a fixed quantity per frame). There's no secret recipe for animating things, you just need to use logic to implement the specific movements you want based on the available state information (i.e. time and frame counts).

Comment: can you sir please give an example code to show the above property.using your code

Comment: Without having nearly enough information to know if it is a useful example, I've added some code that animates both images in something like the way you describe.

Comment: how can i show the 3rd image directly at the overlapping point of the two images without moving it through the coordinates?DO I HAVE TO USE THE IF ELSE STATEMENTS TO SHOW THE 3RD IMAGE OR TO MAKE IT APPEAR DIRECTLY WHEN THE FIRST IMAGE INTERSECTS WITH THE THE SECOND IMAGE.